# WooCommerce addclass to payment gateway selected at checkout

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a class to an element when a payment option is selected on the checkout page of WooCommerce. Here is my code, just for testing using the console to get a response:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#payment_method_extra_payment_option").on( "click", function() {
        console.log('1');
    });
});
```

I am targeting the radio button which has this id name. It is not working.

I have also tried using click(), which also does not working.

I can get this code to work when targeting a piece of text outside the payment options. I don't understand why this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this by using:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {...
```

Instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...
```

I have been able to addClasses now and also amend field validation based on chosen payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The payment options are probably added to the dom after document.ready. So the click event listener won't be added to that element. You should use the .on function in an event-delegation approach:

```
$( "#the_parent_of_the_payment_method_extra_payment_option" ).on( "click", "#the_payment_method_extra_payment_option", function() {
    console.log('1');
});
```

(The id's in this code sample are illustrative)

See this chapter for more information: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have managed to solve my issue using 'ajaxComplet'e as oppose to 'ready'. I will though have a read through your link to see what else I can learn, thank you.

Comment: Your welcome, understanding the timing of events and event listeners in JS will definitely save a future day ;).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.
This works on mine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', "#payment_method_extra_payment_option", function(){
        // do your code here
    });
});
```